# Python command line tool to get chemical structure

Tags: computational-chemistry

In computational chemistry, we need to provide an starting molecular structure to start our calculations. Is there any way to get that from a chemical database? Say, I want to run H2, it would call something like

```
url="www.chemicaldatabase.com"
H2=(url,H2)
```

or it can use smile/other standard symbols for chemical representation.

Comment: Would something like http://blog.matt-swain.com/post/16893587098/chemspipy-a-python-wrapper-for-the-chemspider work?

Comment: For most computations you need 3D structures, so you either need to pull 3D structures directly (example: PyMol and the protein database) or convert identifiers like SMILES into 3D structures, not sure if there's a way to do that. Maybe ObenBabel can do it?

Comment: @chipbuster: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't give you any coordinates.

Comment: @DSVA: Yeah, it would be very hard to list 3D molecular geometry into a database as there are tons of isomers and rotamers involved. I'm running some well known molecular structure using DFT. I don't want to spend time making those initial structures. In ASE, they have a molecular library for some structures, but I am looking for a more detailed database.

Comment: Have a look at molget https://github.com/jensengroup/molget

Answer (score 8):

## There are multiple approaches in Python.

My suggestion would be to use a cheminformatics library like [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/) or [RDKit](http://rdkit.org/) to convert from SMILES (for example) to 3D coordinates.

If you want to grab from chemical databases, I can suggest two approaches:

- [CIRPy](https://github.com/mcs07/CIRpy) - Uses the NIH [chemical resolver](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure) to convert from names, SMILES, etc. into 3D structures.
- [Webel](https://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2009/11/introducing-webel-cheminformatics.html) - This is a web-based cheminformatics tool. I've used it in the past, but I'm not sure if it's still maintained.

There are other databases, including my [PQR](https://pqr.pitt.edu/) and [PubChemQC](http://pccdb.org) that offer QM-optimized geometries.

The catch with databases is that you might want the geometry of a molecule that's not in the database. In that case, Open Babel or RDKit is a better solution.

One other caveat. Nothing I've indicated above does a very good job with metal-containing species. If you want ferrocene, that's a trickier problem with current solutions.

Comment: And as Jan noted above, if you don't care about Python, [molget](https://github.com/jensengroup/molget) is great.

Answer (score 6):

If you are after quantum chemistry [Psi4](http://psicode.org) offers an all-in-one solution:

```
import psi4

mol = psi4.geometry("""
    pubchem:Water
""")

mol.print_out()

scf_e = psi4.energy("SCF", molecule=mol)
```

Comment: I’m curious - since this searches PubChem, what happens if it finds multiple matches (eg ibuprofen) - does this return a list?

Comment: It plays the "I am feeling lucky" google card.

Comment: One other related question - some PubChem searches return molecules with undefined or unknown stereochemistry. Same thing? Would you get a 2D molecule?

Comment: AFAIK an error should be thrown. Psi does not have the right tech to do 2D->3D guesses. We use this a lot in educational settings, but it probably does not pass muster in a professional one.

Comment: Can psi4 uses SMILES as input?